# How to cite a Terms of Service in APA style

Tags: style, citations, apa

I need to cite a Google condition using APA style.

I have the following paragraph, but when I pass it through [Viper](http://www.scanmyessay.com/) I get plagiarized. How shall I do?

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Just to clarify: A plagiarism checker is telling you that quoting this paragraph is plagiarism? That's an entirely separate issue, and it may be worthwhile for you to open a separate question on this. In the meantime, [this page](http://www.scanmyessay.com/blog/how-can-i-paraphrase-without-plagiarising/) may be of help.

Comment: That last answer is of no help. I am also trying to use a websites Terms of Service as a source and can not figure out how to do so properly. I will continue searching and post here when I know.

Answer (score 1):

While I realize that this question is very old, I am providing an answer should others require this information.

For in-text citations, it is sufficient to construct the sentence as follows:

> *According to the terms of service for Google search, images, books, etc ...(n.d.)*

Typically, in APA style, when a source does not list an author or a date of publication, you simply cite the source as (n.d.). If your sentence already references the author/title of the source, then you cite the year of publication only (2013 *or* n.d.). If there is a page number or volume number, you would include that (2013, p.4 *or* vol. 2). And if there is both an author and a page number and you have not already included any of this information in your sentence/paragraph, then you cite it as (Doe, 2013, p.4).

As for your references page, unless it lists an author, it would be something like this:

> *Terms of service.* (2013, October 1 *or* n.d.). Retrieved October 1, 2013, from Google, Google search terms of service website, https://www.google.com/accounts/TOS

If there were an author, it would be:

> Doe, J. (2013, October 1 *or* n.d.). Terms of Service. Retrieved October 1, 2013 from https://www.google.com/accounts/TOS

If the source is a single page and isn't part of a larger work, it would be:

> Doe, J. (2013, October 1 *or* n.d.). Terms of Service. In** *Google Search Account Terms of Service (p. 4 or section number *if there is one -- If none then omit*). Retrieved October 1, 2013 from https://www.google.com/accounts/TOS

[This](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/1/) website is a good reference for APA style if you do not have a copy of the APA style guide.

A rule of thumb for the APA style, for uncommon sources that aren't specifically listed in the style guide, choose the format closest to your source. Include as much information as possible. There are other possibilities depending on the source and the amount of information about the source that you have; these examples may need to be tailored to fit a specific source. But this is the general format.

Comment: Welcome to Writers and thanks for adding this answer.  It's never too late to add information.